# Operations with objects - Practicing for the exam - OOP

Tags: c++, oop

Current state of my solution

```
#include <iostream>

class money {
        int kn, lp;
public:
        void add(int kn, int lp){
                this->kn+=kn;
                this->lp+=lp;
                if(this->lp>=100){
                        this->kn++;
                        this->lp-=100;}
        }
        void print() {
                std::cout<<this->kn<<" kuna";
                if(this->lp!=0) std::cout<<", "<<this->lp<<" lipa";
        }
};

int main () {
        //money a(7, 50) , b(3, 70) , c(2, 80);
        money a;
        //simplified
        a.add(3, 70);
        a.add(2, 80);
        a.print();
}
```

Task requires me to expand the class, so that the below program correctly adds the money and prints it. http://prntscr.com/711bs5

I simplified the task, because I'm still getting to the final solution. But I don't know why does it print garbage? And after I solve that.

Can someone help me in short tips, what's needed to correctly solve the task. Obviously when I'm instancing those objects, I'm supposed to add to object a, the values from objects b and c. But I don't know how to do that, I missed a few lessons.

EDIT: Why do people downvote? Am I missing something? Too trivial question? Bad title?

Comment: Perhaps having meaningful variable names would be a good idea

Comment: The variable names were picked by the professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables before you use them.
When you use variables without initializing them, you get garbage values. For instance, here:

```
this->kn+=kn;
this->lp+=lp;
```

both of them are uninitialized.

For data members of a class, you can initialize using a constructor as follows:

```
money()
{
    kn=0; lp=0;
}
```

So, your code now becomes:

```
#include <iostream>

class money {
int kn, lp;
public:
money()
{
    kn=0; lp=0;
}
void add(int kn, int lp){
    this->kn+=kn;
    this->lp+=lp;
    if(this->lp>=100){
        this->kn += this->lp/100; this->lp %= 100;}
}
void print() {
    std::cout<<this->kn<<" kuna";
    if(this->lp!=0) std::cout<<", "<<this->lp<<" lipa";
}
};

int main () {
//money a(7, 50) , b(3, 70) , c(2, 80);
money a;
//simplified
a.add(3, 70);
a.add(2, 80);
a.print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also change the line, if (this->lp >= 100). What happens if lp = 1000?

Comment: @BenjyKessler: I didn't get you, what is wrong with that statement?

Comment: You have to do this->kn += this->lp/100; this->lp %= 100;

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Still didn't get it, is it some math formula that I am missing?

Comment: I should have changed the variable names before I posted it here, because it uses kn (Croatia Kuna = currency like USD) and lp (something like cents)

Comment: If I have a dollar and 50 cents and somebody gives me 200 cents your code will say I have 2 dollars and 150 cents instead of 3 dollars and 50 cents.

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Oh, I didn't know they were some currencies conversions etc. I assumed them to be normal variables. Thanks! Edited the code.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I assumed all the "cent" values would be 1-99 :P

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: initialize.

For the second part you have to create a method taking another instance of class money as a parameter and add the values of kn and ln to the ones of the existing.

@karma:

It's not a formula, but there is no check how money values have to be entered.

The smartest thing in my opinion would be to check the correct behavior while instancing an object (in the constructor), so that objects can only be of form:

0<=lp<=99;

edit2:

How do you create this method?

For ones, since your add method already exists you can OVERLOAD it. This means you create a method with the same name and return type, but having different parameters.

So you can create another method add and pass a money instance to it, as already mentioned. If you don't understand that, you should really have a look at how methods work and how to create them and that basically anything can be passed to them (not just primitive types).

Comment: I upvote this answer, because it's the only one not coming out with code from nowhere!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , there is code in the link.

Comment: @ArunA.S Links don't matter here as a replacement for a minimal code example shown in the question, as you should well, know.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, yes, that is why I edited and added the code in the question

Comment: How do I create this method?